# WSO2 APIM 3.1.0 - API runs with one user but not for other user with same role

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, wso2, wso2-api-manager

i am working on a multi-tenant app and i have two users with "admin" role. 1st user is "admin" and 2nd user is "abc". When i access token for both users, same scope is returned for both.

```
{
    "access_token": "d479b9e3-1def-31b4-b8a8-3033ae6467ab",
    "refresh_token": "887c386b-2ec7-39c4-9bcf-c286f4dfda40",
    "scope": "app_non-permission app_permission portal_access",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 1862
}
```

Using this token, i call my subscribed API, and it works for "admin" user but fails for "abc". Error message for "abc" user is as below.

```
<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
    <ams:code>900910</ams:code>
    <ams:message>The access token does not allow you to access the requested resource</ams:message>
    <ams:description>Access failure for API: /portal/1, version: 1 status: (900910) - The access token does not allow you to access the requested resource</ams:description>
</ams:fault>
```

I am unable to understand why it works for one user but not for the other even though the users have same role and token API also returns same scope.

Comment: Is the `admin` user is the default admin user?

Comment: Yes it is. However, i have tried making another role and added a new user in it. Then attached the role with relevant scope. It blocks the new user as well.

Comment: Did you create a new admin role and using it(if you created a new admin role, then you need to add scope mappings for that in Admin Portal)? If not this flow should work. Could you please share the steps you followed to do this?

Comment: I am using the default 'admin' role. i have created an 'xyz' tenant, subscribed it to API published by super tenant. The API in carbon.super has scope named "portal_access" which allows users with 'admin' role to use the api. When I use default admin user of xyz tenant to call the token api, it returns "portal_access" scope and using that access token the api works fine. But when I create a user say 'abc' on 'xyz' tenant and assign the same admin role to it, the token api returns "portal_access" scope which is perfect but using the access token gives the above mentioned error.

Comment: What is the APIM version you are using? This has to be a version below 3.2.0 because in 3.2.0 cross tenant subscriptions is not possible..

Comment: yes i am aware of this. i am using 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your explanation it sounds to me like the 'abc' user needs to also subscribe to the API. You might be using the wrong "grant_type" while retrieving the bearer token. [1]
Another possibility would be to add "application sharing" [2] if it's not possible for your 'abc' user to use it's own store application to subscribe to the API.

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Password+Grant

[2]https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Sharing+Applications#SharingApplications-Enablingapplicationsharing

Comment: i am using carbon.super client id and secret in basic auth of token API. super tenant is Saas enabled and I want to login with different tenant users.